# Huggingface pipeline: IndexError: index out of range in self

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, summarization

I'm using the summarization pipeline mentioned in [here](https://huggingface.co/philschmid/bart-large-cnn-samsum)

to summarize a call log. It works in my local instance when the text is small, but when text is large I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 265, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 165, in __call__
    result = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 1074, in __call__
    return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 1081, in run_single
    model_outputs = self.forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 990, in forward
    model_outputs = self._forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py", line 187, in _forward
    output_ids = self.model.generate(**model_inputs, **generate_kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1367, in generate
    model_kwargs = self._prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation(
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 601, in _prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation
    model_kwargs["encoder_outputs"]: ModelOutput = encoder(**encoder_kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 804, in forward
    embed_pos = self.embed_positions(input)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 139, in forward
    return super().forward(positions + self.offset)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 158, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2183, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self
```

But it works in the Hosted inference API of the model card.
Here  is the data I used

```
spk_1:  Hello?
spk_1:  Hi, Customer.
spk_1:  Hi, how are you?
spk_1:  Good, how are you?
spk_1:  Good, good, good.
spk_1:  Let me grab my computer.
spk_1:  I will grab my computer.
spk_1:  Okay, can you hear me?
spk_2:  Hello?
spk_1:  Can you hear me?
spk_1:  Yes, I can.
spk_1:  I'm ready when that's the good of us.
spk_2:  Okay, cool.
spk_2:  Typing www.meet.me
spk_1:  I'm ready.
spk_1:  I'm going to grab my computer.
spk_1:  I'm going to grab my computer.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  I'm going to meet what was it called?
spk_2:  meet.me.
spk_1:  meet me?
spk_2:  meet.me, yes, meet.me.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  Okay, now you should see on the screen it says host a meeting or join a meeting, right?
spk_1:  Well, because it started or joined a meeting.
spk_2:  Yeah, so, so I joined a meeting.
spk_2:  Okay, and the code is Agent with an A, the letter code, so Agent code.
spk_1:  I'm code.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  They're Agent code.
spk_1:  So, all right.
spk_1:  Please enter your name.
spk_1:  Yep.
spk_2:  So, now you should see my screen.
spk_1:  Yes, I see your screen.
spk_2:  All right, cool.
spk_2:  So, you don't have to touch anything else.
spk_2:  So, basically, if you remember correctly, you guys, you registered into our listings.
spk_2:  Program to help build your presence on the search engine.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, this listing program, I run the program because I actually created the program back in 2012.
spk_2:  So, I run the listings program and I'm going to just go over the program today, show you some things.
spk_2:  And, you know, that's where you have a full understanding of it and how it can enhance it as well for you.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  All right, cool.
spk_2:  So, the main reason you got started was because we needed to establish a ranking profile on the search engine for you so that your ranking can be built up organically.
spk_2:  And we can get keywords, pulling you up on the first page, you know, without having to pay for it.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, the listing companies, the prime listing companies that we had you registered in are listed here on the left starting with Yahoo, Bing, Four Square, Yelp, et cetera.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  To the right, you see the green check mark indicates that your business has now been registered in these listings and set up to meet Google's qualifications.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, let me show you one here so you see.
spk_1:  All right.
spk_2:  So, this is your business in easylocal.com.
spk_2:  Now, the first phase of our program is getting your business registered in these listings and setting you up to meet Google's requirements so that Google can now take this listing and use it as a reference point to build your score.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, the first thing that we have to do is make sure your name, address, and phone number are registered.
spk_1:  There you go.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Then we have to make sure that your category, your business category is registered.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, okay.
spk_2:  The science therapy because Google needs to know what type of business you want.
spk_2:  Right.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  Agent, is it possible you can talk any louder?
spk_2:  Can you turn your mind off?
spk_1:  I've got mine.
spk_1:  I'll pop away.
spk_1:  And it just seems very nice.
spk_1:  Can you try again?
spk_1:  Yeah, sure.
spk_2:  So, hold on one second.
spk_2:  Give me a minute.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_1:  Is that better?
spk_2:  Is that any better?
spk_1:  What's that?
spk_1:  Yep.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  Good.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_2:  So, the next thing that we have to have is your business description and hours of operation
spk_2:  registered, which we do.
spk_2:  And then the final requirement, which happens to be the second most important requirement
spk_2:  is you have to have reviews in these listings for Google to, you know, build your ranking
spk_2:  even faster.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, we'll get into the reviews in a minute.
spk_2:  But this is what a completed registered profile looks like minus the reviews.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, we have set your business up in every single directory listing to meet these requirements
spk_2:  set forth by the search engine.
spk_2:  Because when we set your business up to meet these requirements, it allows Google to start
spk_2:  building your ranking naturally now, organically.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_2:  Does that make sense?
spk_1:  Yes, it does.
spk_1:  And now we actually have a good amount of Google reviews.
spk_1:  Those automatically be added to this.
spk_2:  No.
spk_2:  The Google reviews do not syndicate on these listings, unfortunately.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  How many reviews do you have on Google?
spk_1:  I can't.
spk_1:  I don't know off the top and the head, but I want to say probably around 30, I think.
spk_1:  Maybe a dash under 30.
spk_1:  That's how I check out that 24.
spk_1:  So, I'm not sure where it's at now.
spk_2:  Do you do anything specific to get reviews?
spk_1:  Yes.
spk_1:  I actually work with another company that manages my paid at the optimum.
spk_1:  And so, that you also help with some of my internet.
```

Here is the code I used.

```
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="philschmid/bart-large-cnn-samsum")
summarizer(conversation)
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Your `conversation` is longer than the maximum sequence length of the model (1024 tokens).

You can reproduce Huggingface's hosted pipeline by truncating your input:

```py
summarizer(conversation, truncation=True)
```

> [{'summary_text': 'Spk_1 and Spk_2 have registered their business in the listings program to help build their presence on the search engine. They need to establish a ranking profile so that their ranking can be built up organically and they can get keywords, pulling them up on the first page without paying for it.'}]

Comment: setting truncation to True actually does not summarize the text after a certain number of tokens. Is there a way to summarize the entire corpus of text, maybe in batches rather than discarding the text corpus after a certain number of tokens?

Comment: This is an open problem. For example you could create a summary for each chunk of your data, concatenate those summaries, and summarize it.

Comment: How to decide the chunk boundary of the data if I were to split it to n chunks of text and summarize each?

Answer (score 1):

Chunking your inputs and setting truncation seems like the way to go. Otherwise you'll have to retrain or finetune the model to longer inputs.

Given the inputs:

```
conversation_texts = """spk_1:  Hello?
spk_1:  Hi, Customer.
spk_1:  Hi, how are you?
spk_1:  Good, how are you?
spk_1:  Good, good, good.
spk_1:  Let me grab my computer.
spk_1:  I will grab my computer.
spk_1:  Okay, can you hear me?
spk_2:  Hello?
spk_1:  Can you hear me?
spk_1:  Yes, I can.
spk_1:  I'm ready when that's the good of us.
spk_2:  Okay, cool.
spk_2:  Typing www.meet.me
spk_1:  I'm ready.
spk_1:  I'm going to grab my computer.
spk_1:  I'm going to grab my computer.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  I'm going to meet what was it called?
spk_2:  meet.me.
spk_1:  meet me?
spk_2:  meet.me, yes, meet.me.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  Okay, now you should see on the screen it says host a meeting or join a meeting, right?
spk_1:  Well, because it started or joined a meeting.
spk_2:  Yeah, so, so I joined a meeting.
spk_2:  Okay, and the code is Agent with an A, the letter code, so Agent code.
spk_1:  I'm code.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  They're Agent code.
spk_1:  So, all right.
spk_1:  Please enter your name.
spk_1:  Yep.
spk_2:  So, now you should see my screen.
spk_1:  Yes, I see your screen.
spk_2:  All right, cool.
spk_2:  So, you don't have to touch anything else.
spk_2:  So, basically, if you remember correctly, you guys, you registered into our listings.
spk_2:  Program to help build your presence on the search engine.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, this listing program, I run the program because I actually created the program back in 2012.
spk_2:  So, I run the listings program and I'm going to just go over the program today, show you some things.
spk_2:  And, you know, that's where you have a full understanding of it and how it can enhance it as well for you.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  All right, cool.
spk_2:  So, the main reason you got started was because we needed to establish a ranking profile on the search engine for you so that your ranking can be built up organically.
spk_2:  And we can get keywords, pulling you up on the first page, you know, without having to pay for it.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, the listing companies, the prime listing companies that we had you registered in are listed here on the left starting with Yahoo, Bing, Four Square, Yelp, et cetera.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  To the right, you see the green check mark indicates that your business has now been registered in these listings and set up to meet Google's qualifications.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, let me show you one here so you see.
spk_1:  All right.
spk_2:  So, this is your business in easylocal.com.
spk_2:  Now, the first phase of our program is getting your business registered in these listings and setting you up to meet Google's requirements so that Google can now take this listing and use it as a reference point to build your score.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, the first thing that we have to do is make sure your name, address, and phone number are registered.
spk_1:  There you go.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Then we have to make sure that your category, your business category is registered.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, okay.
spk_2:  The science therapy because Google needs to know what type of business you want.
spk_2:  Right.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_1:  Agent, is it possible you can talk any louder?
spk_2:  Can you turn your mind off?
spk_1:  I've got mine.
spk_1:  I'll pop away.
spk_1:  And it just seems very nice.
spk_1:  Can you try again?
spk_1:  Yeah, sure.
spk_2:  So, hold on one second.
spk_2:  Give me a minute.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_1:  Is that better?
spk_2:  Is that any better?
spk_1:  What's that?
spk_1:  Yep.
spk_1:  Okay.
spk_2:  Good.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_2:  So, the next thing that we have to have is your business description and hours of operation
spk_2:  registered, which we do.
spk_2:  And then the final requirement, which happens to be the second most important requirement
spk_2:  is you have to have reviews in these listings for Google to, you know, build your ranking
spk_2:  even faster.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  Now, we'll get into the reviews in a minute.
spk_2:  But this is what a completed registered profile looks like minus the reviews.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  So, we have set your business up in every single directory listing to meet these requirements
spk_2:  set forth by the search engine.
spk_2:  Because when we set your business up to meet these requirements, it allows Google to start
spk_2:  building your ranking naturally now, organically.
spk_2:  All right.
spk_2:  Does that make sense?
spk_1:  Yes, it does.
spk_1:  And now we actually have a good amount of Google reviews.
spk_1:  Those automatically be added to this.
spk_2:  No.
spk_2:  The Google reviews do not syndicate on these listings, unfortunately.
spk_2:  Okay.
spk_2:  How many reviews do you have on Google?
spk_1:  I can't.
spk_1:  I don't know off the top and the head, but I want to say probably around 30, I think.
spk_1:  Maybe a dash under 30.
spk_1:  That's how I check out that 24.
spk_1:  So, I'm not sure where it's at now.
spk_2:  Do you do anything specific to get reviews?
spk_1:  Yes.
spk_1:  I actually work with another company that manages my paid at the optimum.
spk_1:  And so, that you also help with some of my internet."""
```

Here's an example of how chunking the inputs can look like:

```
from transformers import pipeline


summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="philschmid/bart-large-cnn-samsum")

def group_turns_by_speaker(conversation_texts):
  turns = conversation_texts.split('\n')
  prev_speaker = ""
  this_turn = []

  combined_turns = []
  for t in turns:
    speaker, _, text = t.partition(':  ')
    if prev_speaker == speaker:
      this_turn.append(text)
    else:
      if this_turn:
        combined_turns.append(speaker + ": " + " <sep> ".join(this_turn))
        this_turn = []
      this_turn = [text]
    prev_speaker = speaker
  if this_turn:
    combined_turns.append(speaker + ": " + " <sep> ".join(this_turn))
  return combined_turns

def chunk_turns(turns_by_speakers):
  chunks = []
  this_chunk = []
  this_len = 0
  for turn in turns_by_speakers:
    if this_len + len(turn) > 1000:  # Taking max 1000 chars as inputs.
      chunks.append(this_chunk)
      this_chunk = [turn]
      this_len = len(turn)
    else:
      this_chunk.append(turn)
      this_len += len(turn)
  if this_chunk:
    chunks.append(this_chunk)
  return chunks

for chunk in chunk_turns(group_turns_by_speaker(conversation_texts)):
  for summary in summarizer(" <sep> ".join(chunk)):
    print(summary)
```